# Duplicating a table in word document opened using win32 in python

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a ms-word document opened using win32 in python, I want to duplicate a table which somewhere in the middle of the word document.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the Word table through win32com.

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = 0
doc = word.Documents.Open('your file path')
```

And you can check the table numbers in the document:

```
doc.Tables.Count
```

**Note:Unlike python, Word indexing starts at 1**

You can traverse a table in the following ways:

```
table = doc.Tables(1)       #You can choose the table you need
for row in range(1,table.Rows.Count + 1):
    for col in range(1,table.Columns.Count + 1):
        print(table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text)
```

In this way, the function of obtaining the contents of the table is realized. Of course, if you want to re-copy the contents of this table to another table, you can recreate a table and add it to the Word document.

Here is the complete Sample:

```
import win32com.client as win32
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = 0
doc = word.Documents.Open('test.docx')

tableNum = doc.Tables.Count     #the table numbers 

print(doc.Tables.Count)

location = doc.Range()
location.Move() # place table at the end 
table = doc.Tables(1)       #You can choose the table you need
table2 = doc.Content.Tables.Add(location, table.Rows.Count, table.Columns.Count)
table2.AutoFormat(36)

for row in range(1,table.Rows.Count + 1):
    for col in range(1,table.Columns.Count + 1):
        print(table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text)
        table2.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text = table.Cell(Row = row,Column = col).Range.Text

doc.Close()     #Don't forget to close the document
word.Quit()
```

This is my test.docx:

[image]

When I run the program, it works for me:

[image]

Comment: *"COM indexing starts at 1"* - COM uses [SAFEARRAY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/march/introducing-the-safearray-data-structure)'s. `SAFEARRAY`'s allow for *arbitrary* indexing, controlled by the `SAFEARRAYBOUND` field. Word may have chosen 1 for the lower bound, but that's unrelated to COM.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.But table is in the mid of the word document.For example word document has 10 pages.First  few pages has some text and then there is a table1, now I want to make duplicate copy of this table1; and place the new table right after table1. the newly created table should have same font type and font size.

Comment: @pravinshinde This function is based on the number of tables in the document to select regardless of the text. The style of the text can be changed according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to align the text in cells of the table